# Getting anonymous data( physically don't exist ) from Hive query in the final results ( A LEFT JOIN B )

Tags: sql, hive, mapreduce, presto

I am doing a LEFT JOIN( A LEFT JOIN B ) between two tables A and B and writing the results into the final table. The left table A has unique rows and table B has one row per each id. When I run the above left join query on I am getting duplicates( unknowns from Table B. They physically do not exist  in Table B ) in the final output. The suspicious part is there are rows coming out in the final result which do not exist in Table B.  I tried testing the query in multiple ways.

**Types of Unit Tests:**

1. Took a small sample and applied WHERE clause for both tables A,B and ran the query. There are no dups and expected output is coming out without dups.
2. Took a small sample only for table A and did a left join with B that has entire data and ran the query. The final result has dups ( dups come with unknown data that do not exist in Table B ) wrote into a Hive brand new table without partitioning.
3. Took a small sample only for table A and did a left join with B that has entire data and ran the query. The final result has dups ( dups come with unknown data that do not exist in Table B ) ( Just ran only the SELECT query )

Can anybody share your thoughts why this could be happening?

Comment: I would recommend to `GROUP BY/HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` on the tables for the join keys. That will give you the root cause.

Comment: I have done that. The data which is showing up in the results doesn't even exist when I query on table B.

Comment: Not sure if you are using WHERE clause in your test 2 & 3 (as you have done in 1).

Comment: I am intentionally not using WHERE clause for table B to filter out on the sample. The table B has only one row per id.

Comment: Got the solution for this problem. The data types of the join keys do not match and due to that wrong match is happening and wring values are getting populated.